# can we use conditions in sanity schema

Tags: database, backend, content-management-system, sanity, headless-cms

i have a schema named -'**category**', the other scheme is named -'**Box**' and the category scheme is **referenced** inside the **'Box' schema** .

What i want is if there are **2 categories ('catg 1' and 'catg2')**, and **2 blockContents (b1 and b2)** with specific things as per requirements of both categories, then If I select the category **'catg1'** , then below that the blockContent that **show should be b1 below that ,not the b2.**